# Not able to navigate from Activity to a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to navigate from activity to a fragment, but I have got caught with an error. I have posted my complete code. Please help me in solving this problem. All suggestions are welcome. Please find my code below:

EditScreen.java:

```
public class EditScreen extends ActionBarActivity  {

    Toolbar toolbar;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_screen);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

 }

public void update (View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailViewFragmentActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);



    }

 }
```

DetailViewFragment.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class DetailViewFragment extends Fragment {

public DetailViewFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_view, container, false);


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


 }

}
```

DetailViewFragmentActivity.java:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class DetailViewFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_detail_view);

        DetailViewFragment f1 = new DetailViewFragment();

        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
        // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        f1.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_detail, f1).commit();

    }
}
```

fragment_detail_view.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ms.t.tms.DetailViewFragment"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" ></include>
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/update"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:onClick="update"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat trace:

```
02-16 15:08:41.492      965-965/com.ms.t.tms E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ms.t.tms, PID: 965
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.ms.t.tms/com.ms.t.tms.DetailViewFragmentActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1761)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3736)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3697)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4007)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3975)
            at com.ms.t.tms.EditScreen.update(EditScreen.java:65)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ms.t.tms" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_screen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailViewFragActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail_view_frag" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I select Update method from EditScreen, I want to get navigated to detail view which is a fragment. I am getting the error posted above, when I select Update button. Please let me know my mistake. Thanks in advance.
Please let me know if more information needed.

Comment: As in Log :: `Have you declared DetailViewFragmentActivity activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: Register `DetailViewFragmentActivity` in your `manifest.xml`

Comment: I have declared it. I have edited the question and have included my manifest file also. Any other suggestions?? or are there any problem in my manifest file?

Comment: @keshavkowshik: you have not declare `DetailViewFragmentActivity` Activity in Manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change

```
  android:name=".DetailViewFragActivity"
```

to

```
  android:name=".DetailViewFragmentActivity"
```

Check activity name. It's `DetailViewFragmentActivity` not `DetailViewFragActivity`